# How to send message through dialog box?

Tags: android

In my application I am clicking one share image button and four options facebook, twitter, mail and messaging are showing through alert Dialog box. I want to send message throuh fourth option(Messaging). How to do that. I have created dialog box like this. What will be the code to send the message to any mob no.

Here is my code.....

```
sharebuton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override`enter code here`
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final CharSequence[] items = {"Facebook","Twitter", "E-Mail", "Messaging"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ProgramInfoActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Share the Program");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {   
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {   
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();          
            }});
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use default share Intent.

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "message subject");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Pick a Share method"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if i am using above code, Its showing all social network application. I want to share through only four network facebook,twitter,email and messaging.